# selecting all anchor elements but not :first-child anchor in a class group

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have to hide all anchor elements but not first child of class group. Before anchors starting i place h2 tag. with this h2 i cant able to get exact result .

[View in JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshamk/Z7qD3/)

Html

```
 <div id="main" >
        <div class="album">
            <h2>title 1 </h2>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/0.jpg"> 
                show this
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/1.jpg"> 
                not show
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/2.jpg"> 
                not show                           
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/3.jpg"> 
                not show                          
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/4.jpg"> 
                not show                           
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/5.jpg"> 
                not show                           
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/6.jpg"> 
                not show                            
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="album">
            <h2>title 2 </h2>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/0.jpg"> 
                show this
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/1.jpg"> 
                not show
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/2.jpg"> 
                not show                           
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/3.jpg"> 
                not show                            
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/4.jpg"> 
                not show                           
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/5.jpg"> 
                not show                           
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/6.jpg"> 
                not show                           
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="album">
            <h2>title3 </h2>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/0.jpg"> 
                show this
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/1.jpg"> 
                not show
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/2.jpg"> 
                not show                            
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/3.jpg"> 
                not show                            
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/4.jpg"> 
                not show                            
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/5.jpg"> 
                not show                           
            </a>
            <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/6.jpg"> 
                not show                            
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

:Expected Result:

**title 1** 
show this

**title 2** 
show this

**title 3** 
show this

i applied css as following but not working.

```
.album  a:not(:first-child) {
        display:none;
    }
```

i am getting the correct result when i omit

```
<h2>...</h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.album  a:not(:first-of-type) {
    display:none;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7qD3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
.album a {
    display:none;
}
.album a:first-of-type {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7qD3/2/)**

**The CSS Change:**

```
.album a{display:none;}
.album a:first-of-type{display:block;}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="main" >
    <div class="album">
        <h2>title 1 </h2>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/0.jpg"> 
            show this
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/1.jpg"> 
            not show
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/2.jpg"> 
            not show                           
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/3.jpg"> 
            not show                          
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/4.jpg"> 
            not show                           
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/5.jpg"> 
            not show                           
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/6.jpg"> 
            not show                            
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="album">
        <h2>title 2 </h2>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/0.jpg"> 
            show this
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/1.jpg"> 
            not show
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/2.jpg"> 
            not show                           
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/3.jpg"> 
            not show                            
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/4.jpg"> 
            not show                           
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/5.jpg"> 
            not show                           
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/6.jpg"> 
            not show                           
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="album">
        <h2>title3 </h2>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/0.jpg"> 
            show this
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/1.jpg"> 
            not show
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/2.jpg"> 
            not show                            
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/3.jpg"> 
            not show                            
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/4.jpg"> 
            not show                            
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/5.jpg"> 
            not show                           
        </a>
        <a title="Campus photo" href="images/gallery/campus/6.jpg"> 
            not show                            
        </a>
    </div>
```

css

```
.album a{
display:none;
 }
 .album a:nth-child(2){
display:block;
 }
 .album h2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px;
 }
 .album{
clear:both;
 }
```

result should look like

[image]

THANKS!